# Convert Bufferedimage to QPixmap Java QTJambi

Tags: qt, qt-jambi

I am using QTJambi and I need to convert **BufferedImage** into **QPixmap**.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```
public QPixmap convertBufferedImageToQPixmap(BufferedImage img){
    QPixmap result = new QPixmap(new QSize(img.getWidth(),img.getHeight()));
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        boolean foundWriter = ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", baos);
        result.loadFromData(baos.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```